# List of phone numbers being consistent

Tags: c#

Hi good people of stackoverflow

I have a problem that i don't know how to solve and i need help here it goes :

Write function that will analyze a list of phone numbers and determine if it is consistent, in the way that no telephone number is the prefix of another one in the list.

Take a look at this example:

```
Information 988
Mike 43722451
Steven 98816740
```

In the example above, we can not reach Steven, because the telecom center would direct us to the Information line as soon as you had entered 988, which happen to be the first 3 digits of Steven's phone number. So this list would not be consistent.

Assume that the input is a list of strings, where each string has a maximum length of 10 characters. Feel free to code in any language that is familiar to you.

....this was for an interview and as you assume i didn't solve it so if someone can do this and give me a little explanation it would help me a lot..

Comment: Even if you couldn't solve it for the interview when posting a question on SO you need to show what you have tried

Comment: Question should contain code and description of problem which you have with that code - error or actual/expected results

Comment: Take a look at string.StartsWith() method.

Comment: And take a look at some basic C# tutorials online...

Comment: Sounds like a case for a Huffman Tree.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to sort the collection lexicographically, and then scan it:

```
  // let's for instance, organize numbers as an array
  string[] numbers = new string[] {
    "988",       // <- this is a prefix of "98816740"
    "43722451",
    "98816740",  // <- has a prefix "988" which is within the collection
    "123",
    "456",
  };

  Array.Sort(numbers);

  for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
    if (numbers[i].StartsWith(numbers[i - 1])) {
      //TODO: Conflict found, put relevant code here
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is a prefix of {1}", numbers[i - 1], numbers[i]);
    }
```

As you can see the algorithm has `O(n * log(n))` complexity.

**Edit:** in general case, if you're given a `string` you have to *extract features* (`name` and `number`), e.g. with *regular expressions*:

```
  string data = "Information 988 Mike 43722451 Steven 98816740";

  var records = Regex
    .Matches(data, @"(?<name>\w+)\s*(?<number>[0-9]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => new {
      name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
      number = match.Groups["number"].Value, })
    .OrderBy(item => item.number)
    .ToArray();

  for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; ++i) {
    if (records[i].number.StartsWith(records[i - 1].number)) {
      // records[i - 1] number is a prefix of records[i] number
      //TODO: put relevant code here  

      Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" conflicts with \"{1}\": {2} is a prefix of {3}",
        records[i - 1].name, records[i].name, records[i - 1].number, records[i].number);
    }
  }
```

Outcome:

```
  "Information" conflicts with "Steven": 988 is a prefix of 98816740
```

Comment: You are just comparing one element with the previous one, but try to test *"91125426","97625992","911", "9113"* .....

Answer (score 2):

```
var numbers = new List<string> {
  "988",
  "1234567",
  "988448484",
  "62615",
  "6261545"
};

foreach(var s in numbers) {
  if (numbers.Any(x => x.StartsWith(s) && x != s))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Prints `988` and `62615`

Comment: Your algorithm has `O(n**2)` complexity; in case you have a long (say 1 million items) list of numbers the implementation will too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Tries will help, and the tc should be O(n)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).